# Can PWM safely be considered as effectively lowering voltage?

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, pwm

Specifically with LEDs which need constant current more than voltage. I'm using those 30V,  100 Watt LEDs (which strangly draw less than 1A) and due to using four 11V batteries in series to power them they need to be "dimmed' to 30 volts. My voltage regulators are only rated for 35V, so would a microcontroller's PWM with a MOSFET be a safe form of protecting the LEDs from would could otherwise be over voltage/current?

I don't know if flickering could be an issue, but it doesn't matter too much to me and I could research how to include capacitors and/or inductors to reduce it.

Comment: Those "100W" LEDs draw less tha 1A because the "100W" means "light output equivalent to a 100W incandescent bulb". Which isn't much light, as most of the 100W is turned into heat.

Comment: For some reason the specifications for the LEDs list that they have a forward current of 3 amps and that they are equivalent to a 1000W incandescent. Either way, they are extremely bright and get extremely hot

Comment: That is quite unusual. No wonder they get hot, even with the efficiency of LEDs most of the 100W is still turned into heat. That's the sort of heat which usually requires active cooling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PWM does not lower the (peak) voltage. PWM reduces the **average current** (and in consequence the average power).

In case of LEDs - they don't care much about the voltage, it is the current that can destroy them (both forward and reverse). So you have to take care not to exceed their peak current rating.

To reduce voltage you would have to add an inductor, catch diode and capacitors to make a *buck converter* which *does* lower the voltage.

Comment: I think 'LEDs don't care much about the voltage' is misleading - LEDs, like all diodes, have a well defined relationship between forward voltage and forward current, and for voltages more than a little bit above the normal operating range the current would be very large indeed. So if you try to apply 40 V to an LED whose Vf is 30 V, even for a short time, it will try to draw a very large current and either the power supply will fail to deliver that current, possibly destroying the power supply, or it will succeed and probably destroy the LED.

Comment: 30V LEDs are likely to be LED *modules*, which may or may not contain a current limiter (probably just a resitor if they do)

Answer (score 3):

PWM alone will not 'effectively lower voltage' for this purpose.   The problem is, PWM makes a voltage which is a function of time, it has MANY DIFFERENT VALUES, not a limited range (such as an LED can tolerate).   What endangers an LED may be an average, RMS average, peak value of V, or a peak value of current (which is a  nonlinear function of voltage applied).

Assuming 90 lumens/watt, and a "100W equivalent" lamp means 900 lumens, you want
about 10W into your circa 30V  LED load.   330 mA DC is the desired current.

A linear regulator (LM317) could work; it needs only to be rated for the
difference of input and output voltages (44V - 30V = 14V) and not for
the 44V.   The most effective way to regulate current is to use a current sense resistor, as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Fio9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor and regulator will get warm, so you'll want a heatsink.

For better power efficiency, PWM followed by a filter inductor and a catch diode is called a 'buck' voltage dropper.  It filters but won't regulate (lacking any kind of feedback), so the battery condition and ambient temperature will affect the
current.  Buck regulators are available, that will regulate, dissipate nearly no heat, improve battery lifetime.  Many suitable modules are based on LM2596.

Answer (score 2):

PWM will reduce the average voltage and current to the LEDs.

The peak voltage will be the PWM peak and it will determine the peak current.

1. Check that your design does not exceed specified LED peak voltage.
2. Check that your design does not exceed specified LED peak current.
3. Check that if using peak current that the maximum duty cycle at that current is not exceeded. e.g., 1 A for 5 ms at 20% duty cycle.

Comment: If the PWM signal is on for just a few milliseconds, I assume the peak would still be 40V along with the peak current so would it still be considered unsafe for a 30V LED? A multimeter would read the PWM output differently than an oscilloscope, but to an LED, would high over voltage for any amount of time damage and burn the diodes? or is there an amount of time they need to start burning

Comment: Correct. However, if you add a series inductor and freewheeling diode, you just made a buck converter that will give the LEDs the constant(ish) current they want.